# Call APIs over Http from Webpage served over Https

Tags: apache, jetty

We have a Java/Jetty server. The servlets on this server are called by some of our internal applications over http.
I have been asked to create a webapp /website which will use many of these servlets / api. 
However this is an external customer facing website and needs to be served over https / ssl. The servelet urls look like
http://internalServer:9999?parameters.
Now my webapp is ready and has been deployed on Apache on Debian. Everything works fine but as soon as I enable
https/ssl the backend calls do not go through. On chrome I get "Mixed content. Page was loaded on https but is requestig resource over http...". On Safari I get -could not load resource due to access control checks.

I understand the reasons for these errors but I would like to know ways to solve this. 
 I have full control over apache server and website code.
 I have very limited control over internal jetty server and no control over servelt code.(don't want to mess with existing apps). 
Is there something I can do just with apache configuration? can I use it as a reverse proxy for the Jetty(http) server? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to call an http service from an https site you will have `Mixed content` error.

You can avoid that error using apache2 proxy settings inside your `example.org.conf`
You can find it inside the folder `/apache2/sites-enabled`

Add some code:

```py
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ...
   ProxyPass /service1 http://internalServer:9999
   ProxyPassReverse /service1 http://internalServer:9999
</VirtuaHost>
```

From your https site you have to fetch the url

```py
https://example.org/service1`
```

to reach the service.

In that way you can call your services http from a https site.

Answer (score 0):

> "Mixed content. Page was loaded on https but is requestig resource over http..."

That error message means your HTML has resources that are being requested over `http://...` specifically.

You'll need to fix your HTML (and any references in javascript and css) that request resources (or references resources) to also use `https://....`